# Magento Export Issue

Tags: magento, module, report

We are doing a product CSV custom report. But the system is showing memory issue for a month date range. Is any option to create the same?                                                                          thanks                                                                         Rajath

Comment: show the proper error.

Comment: Its leading to blank page, when the query enter in phpmyadmin its also become stuck.